# Browser extension that hides DIVs containing a certain word

Tags: web-browser, plug-in

On a specific webpage I'd like to hide DIVs that contain paragraphs with a certain word. Is there an extension that does that?

Their class is the same as for ones I'd like to see, so there is no possibility to hide them based on other attributes, only content.

It doesn't matter for which browser it is, I'll use any browser that has such an extension. OS can be macOS, Linux or Windows (I use all of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out myself. Adblock Ultimate works with the following custom rule:

```
example.com#?#div:-abp-has(> p:-abp-contains(certain-word))
```

Comment: Thanks for self-answering! Could you please include a link to Adblock Ultimate – and what browsers it is available for? Side-note: from the looks of your expression, that could also work with [uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/), which is available for Firefox, Chrome/Chromium, MS Edge and Safari.

Comment: Not sure about uBlock Origin, but Adblock Plus supports such syntax and is probably more popular choice than Adblock Ultimate I mentioned before: https://adblockplus.org/filter-cheatsheet

Comment: In a way, yeah. But it somehow got its reputation tainted with their "acceptable ads" integration.